# How do I create a class in JS using ES6 conventions?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have a class "dog" and want its prototype to be a new class, animal. How do I create this in JS using ES6 syntax?

Comment: [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/yapogiqena/edit?js,console)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Check this link for [ES6 class definition](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/).

Answer (score 3):

A class in ES6 is defined as it follows. You mentioned Dog, so let's create a class named Dog:

```
class Dog{
    constructor(breed, age){
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;
    }
    // Method to make the dog jump 
    jump (){
        // Make it jump in some way
    }
}
```

So, that's how a class is defined in ES6. The things that may "return" some information are called "methods". In this case, jump() is a method. If you want it to return something you just write `return <some-object/value>;` in the method's last line.

If prior to Dog, you have an `Animal` class, you can make your Dog class to extend the Animal class as follows:

`class Dog extends Animal`

This is called "inheritance" in programming. So your Dog class/object will inherit all methods avaialable in the class Animal.